# oAuth 2.0 Database structure

Tags: database, oauth

I am looking to implement oAuth in my current application. What is a good database structure to store information required, such as token etc-era. Are there any standards?

Comment: I suppose you mean a database for an OAuth server/provider?

Comment: No, database structure

Comment: To do what? Do you need to store rows of token for a client application?

Comment: To store users via twitter, fb etc

Answer (score 13):

I was considering the same thing.  In general, I'm doing:

```
user_oauth_info
-------------------------------
id (int auto-inc)
user_id (int)
oauth_provider (varchar 20)
acccess_token (varchar 40)
refresh_token  (varchar 40)   
expiry_date (datetime)
```

A refresh_token is provided by SalesForce; does not expired and is used to get refreshed access_tokens.  They only give you one if your callback URL is a mobile device, though, which is irritating.

Comment: Update: There are better suggestions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534337/what-is-the-recommended-database-structure-for-oauth-provider?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You could start with what VS2012 suggests for their MVC framework:

**webpages_OAuthMembership**

```
Provider nvarchar(30) (clustered primary key)
ProviderUserId nvarchar(100) (clustered primary key)
UserId int
```

**webpages_Membership**

```
UserId int (Primary Key)
CreateDate datetime
ConfirmationToken nvarchar(128)
IsConfirmed bit
LastPasswordFailureDate datetime
PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess int
Password nvarchar(128)
PasswordChangedDate datetime
PasswordSalt nvarchar(128)
PasswordVerificationToken nvarchar(128)
PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate datetime
```

Then define your own Users table, something like:

```
UserID int (Primary Key)
UserName nvarchar(80)
Name nvarchar(80)
Surname nvarchar(80)
```

I don't really have a reason for doing it this way, but I guess that the Microsoft people that came up with this schema know way more about this than I do, so I think it's great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

[This default scheme database oauth2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql)

I use this with spring boot

Answer (score -4):

I think google oAuth tutorial will make you help

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2